# rpmbuild fails with parenthesis in name

Tags: jenkins, rpm

I am building RPMs with maven, triggered by Jenkins. Someone decided it was a good idea to have ( and ) in jenkins job names.

This breaks my rpm generation, and it's immediately evident what's wrong from Jenkins console output:

```
[WARNING] /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.7L55LG: line 37: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

In /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.7L55LG line 37 we have

```
mv /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myjenkinsjob-(WEB-SITE)  \ 
/workspace/target/rpm/mywebsite/tmp-buildroot/* $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
```

(WEB-SITE) is not escaped or quoted.

The question I have is, where is this shell script generated, and how can I modify it?

Comment: I'm guessing in the rpmbuild source code. But being a noob, perhaps someone could point out where the source code is? rpm.org (?) - but where?

Answer (score 0):

See the %install section of the spec file.